# Getting the value of XML field matching a property via XPATH

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I've got a really odd XML schema that's causing me unecessary grief and woe.

I need to get the value of an **IMAGEFILENAME** node that has a property of "hide".

The XML schema looks something like:

```
<PHOTOS>
    <IMAGETHUMBFILENAME/>
    <IMAGECAPTION>
        This is a caption
    </IMAGECAPTION>
    <PRINTQUALITYIMAGE>
        /mylocation/filename1.jpg
    </PRINTQUALITYIMAGE>
    <IMAGEFILENAME pictype="show">
        /mylocation/filename2.jpg
    </IMAGEFILENAME>
    <IMAGETHUMBFILENAME/>
    <IMAGECAPTION>This is another caption</IMAGECAPTION>
    <PRINTQUALITYIMAGE>
        /mylocation/filename3.jpg
    </PRINTQUALITYIMAGE>
    <IMAGEFILENAME pictype="hide">
        /mylocation/filename4.jpg
    </IMAGEFILENAME>
    <IMAGETHUMBFILENAME/>
</PHOTOS>
```

And I've managed to come up with the following XPATH using PHP:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/PHOTOS/IMAGEFILENAME[@pictype="hide"]');
var_dump($nodes);
```

When I do a dump of the $nodes var what I'd hope to see (and what I want) is to get the value **/mylocation/filename4.jpg**. Instead what I'm getting is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#333 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["pictype"]=>
      string(10) "hide"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried various combinations of **/parent**, **/text()** and **/node()** but with no joy at all.

Please somebody tell me what a muppet I'm being and put me out of my misery. Either that or is the schema being problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have array of SimpleXMLElements.

To get string representation of `SimpleXMLElement` you can just `echo` it:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/PHOTOS/IMAGEFILENAME[@pictype="hide"]');
echo $nodes[0];   // I used `[]` notation to get first element of array
```

To use string representation of `SimpleXMLElement` later in your code you can convert it to string explicitly:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/PHOTOS/IMAGEFILENAME[@pictype="hide"]');
$node_str = strval($nodes[0]);  // still `[]` notation
```

Comment: You're a genius and I am a muppet. Particularly with the amount of time I've wasted... Thank you, sir.